# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object где ошибка?

Tags: php, mysql

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/d9/public_html/t3/s3.php on line 60

вот код

```
$tt = $_SESSION['numarul'];
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'd3', 'password')
or die('Не удалось соединиться: '.mysql_error());
echo 'Соединение успешно установлено';
mysql_select_db('d5') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных');

// Выполняем SQL-запрос
$result_set = $link - > query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `ids` = "'.$link - > real_escape_string($tt).'"');
while ($row = $result_set - > fetch_assoc()) {
  $namessUTILIZATOR = $row['numele'];
  $punteUTILIZATOR = $row['puncte'];
  $timpul = time();
}

// Закрываем соединение
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: какая из этих строк имеет номер 60?

Comment: А `- >` вообще легально?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Думаю вполне легально, как операторы минус и больше :) (как раз то же самое хотел спросить)

Comment: @Mike нее .... будет `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' ` ........но ошибка скорее всего потому,что в `mysql_select_db` не указан ресурс

Comment: тогда не ясно как оно доходит до ошибки отсутствия объекта

Comment: $result_set = $link->query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `ids` = "' .$link->real_escape_string($tt) .'"' ); - это 60 строка

Comment: Вы присоединились "процедурным" методом, а запрос пытаетесь выполнить "объектным" методом.

Comment: Кстати, а почему вы коннект открываете с помощю mysql_connect. query - это скорее всего из mysqli или PDO. Нельзя смешивать функции из разных библиотек. А про функции mysql_* вообще надо забить и никогда их не использовать

Comment: как правилино будет ?

Comment: А вы какую библиотеку вообще собираетесь использовать ?

Comment: Просто берете документацию и читаете. Предположим ваш query из PDO. http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Comment: любую чтоб работало главное

Comment: @MasterDons ну вот вам всё дали, дальше действовать -- ваша очередь

Comment: Что самое удивительное, такая конструкция гибридная по тестированию с `mysqli` у меня прокатила и дала результат :-)

Comment: `mysql_*` функции древние как мамонты и уже не поддерживается в актуальных версиях php